# Calculate textbox input Total times textbox input percent equals new input textbox total

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, calculated-field

I have looked up and down trying to figure this out, I am trying to make a simple calculation on change event with 3 textbox inputs

> 1. Cost of Item textbox
> 2. Discount Percentage which would be entered manually of value exp:
>    29
> 3. Total: which will equal the Cost *'s Discount equal the new Total.

When Discount or Cost is changed then the Total will change with them
I have the javascript of getting the total somewhat...but i also need to format the Cost & Total from numeric to currency instead of 2500 it formats to $2,500.00 etc

Any help is appreciated im new to this and still learning but im just lost

```
var number = 14000;
var percentToGet = 29;
var percent = (percentToGet / 100) * number;
alert(percentToGet + "% of " + number + " is " + percent);
function calculatePercent(percent, num){
return (percent / 100) * num;


This gives me the discount of 4,060 of 14,000 which total becomes 9,940
```

I may need to use jquery or ajax but i have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't an help forum for learning basic programming but a platform for questions and answers that can then benefit other people too. Try forming a clear and focused question, also showing your own efforts and research.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It looks like you're asking two different questions, how to change the total value when the value or discount changes and how to format the total value. For the first one, see the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event#examples) event, or the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event. For the second one, you might want to take a look at [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hope below test implementation can help , please input all item price and discount to observe the result 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Form</title>
    <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Calculate Discount </h1>
        <form id="discountForm">
            <div class="row mb-3">
            
                <div  class="row col-md-12">
                
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Item Name</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
                    Item Price
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    Item Price After Dicount
           </div>                
                    
                </div>
                
                 
                <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
                
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Item 1</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item__1">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="discunt_price_1">
                    
           </div>                    
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
                
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="name" class="form-label">Item 2</label>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item__2">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="discunt_price_2">
                    
           </div>                    
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
                
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                   
                    Discount %
                    
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount" >
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    
           </div>                    
                    
                </div>
                
                <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
                
                   <div class="col-md-3">
                    
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    Total After Discount
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="total_price">
                    
           </div>                    
                    
                </div>
                
                
               
            </div>
           
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>-->
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Include Bootstrap JS (optional) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    
       const isDigit = (value) => /^\d+$/.test(value) ;   


       const calculatePercent = (percent, num) => {          
          return num - ((percent / 100) * num);     
       }
       
       const setDiscountPrice = () => {
           
            let flagInputError = false;
            $("[id^='item__']").each(function (e) {
               
               
               let id = $(this).attr('id').replace("item__", "");
               let itemPrice = $("#item__"+id).val();
               let discount = $("#discount").val();
               
               if(isDigit(itemPrice) && isDigit(discount)) { 
                  $("#discunt_price_"+id).html(calculatePercent(discount, itemPrice).toFixed(2));   
               }
               else {
                  flagInputError = true;        
               } 
               
            });
            
            if(flagInputError) {
               
               $("[id^='item__']").each(function (e) {
               
             let id = $(this).attr('id').replace("item__", "");        
            $("#discunt_price_"+id).html("");
            $("#total_price").html("");
           });
            
            }
            else {
            
                let total = 0;
                $("[id^='item__']").each(function (e) {
               
             let id = $(this).attr('id').replace("item__", "");
            total += parseFloat($("#discunt_price_"+id).html());           
            
           });
           
           $("#total_price").html(total.toFixed(2));
            }
       
       }
       
       
       $(document).ready(function() {
        
        var inputs = $('#discountForm input');
        
        inputs.change(function() {
           
            setDiscountPrice();
        });
        
        
    });
    </script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From what i can tell of the script and how everything is called it should be working, unfortunately nothing is changing when entered into the input boxes

Comment: @Jason good day, kindly fill up all the input fields with number. currently setDiscountPrice method called on input field change , you can call it on key up also.

Comment: thanks what i was needing!! thank you

Comment: @Jason happy to see it work for you. Kindly accept the answer and give some positive votes, it will inspire me to contribute more!